# Change top and left property based on offSet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well what I want to achieve is that my top and left property on a div get updated every time I click on a element in the page the Div get updated with the properties where the mouse was.

Right now I have no idea why this doesn't work.

I simple a have a big div with alot of elementes repeated with the a ng click function in it.

```
ng-click="mapCurrentPerson($event)"
```

I have in my controller this functions, where I log the offset of the $event bind it to a variable and try to update the variable in the page using the ng-style property

```
        $scope.currentX = 0;
        $scope.currentY = 0;

        $scope.mapCurrentPerson = function(event) {

            var x = event.offsetX;
            var y = event.offsetY;

            console.log('x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);

            $scope.$watch('currentX', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log(newValue, oldValue);
                $scope.currentX = '' + x + 'px';
            });

            $scope.$watch('currentY', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log(newValue, oldValue);
                $scope.currentY = '' + y + 'px';
            });

        }
```

And my html where the div needs to get updated based on the click properties

```
<div class="current-person"
         ng-style="{'top': currentX,
                    'left':currentY}">
        <!--<img src="{{ current.photo }}" class="current-photo">-->
    </div>
```

The start of the $scope.currentX and Y are just working great on the NG style but it doesn't get updated when I change the scope properties no matter what I try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$scope.coordinates={};
$scope.coordinates.currentX=0;
$scope.coordinate.currentY=0;
```

Comment: May be in `ng-style` you should use not only numbers but `px`.

Comment: I was trying to just get the px from the controller, $scope.currentY = '' + y + 'px';. gonna check if it really matters

Comment: `top` property should be with `position: absolute`. Or use `margin-top` instead.

Comment: I created jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4j5yp8q6/1/ and it worked for me. Check, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98088/discussion-between-olga-akhmetova-and-dennis).